# CSS/JS: Align tiles left and top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having thumbnails with always the **same image-width**, and a possible different image-height.

Now, I want to align them all in order to have no 'gaps' in my thumbnails/tile-overview. I'm only floating them left now. But that gives the result below.

Isn't there a JS library available for this? (= align tiles with the same width, different height, without any gaps?)

[image: Float images]

Comment: link to website/fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Try http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a jQuery plugin named Masonry. It's known for being a pain in the arse though. Depending on the scale of your application I'd use a CSS3 or flex-box alternative.

jQuery Masonry - http://masonry.desandro.com/

CSS3 Masonry - http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Flex-Box Masonry - http://thenewcode.com/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox

Hope these links help.
:)

Answer (score 0):

The still not so good column can maybe help you..
[Can i use column?](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)

```css
div.wrapper {
  -webkit-columns: 300px 2;
  -moz-columns: 300px 2;
  columns: 300px 2;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px dotted rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-column-rule: 1px dotted rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule: 1px dotted rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-h-c-300-450-2.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-h-c-300-601-10.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-h-c-300-306-10.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-300-148-2.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-h-c-300-627-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-h-c-300-460-8.jpg">
</div>
```